# Chi-square and repeated measure

Tags: repeated-measures, chi-squared-test, survey

I have a survey of 20 questions; answers are given on the 5-point Likert scale.

Goal: to understand whether the answer on the first question affects answers on other questions.

Normally speaking I would be compiling a contingency table for  "the first question vs another question" and running the chi-squared test. However, here I need to compare Q1 with Q2, Q1 with Q3, ..., Q1 with Q20. Do I understand correctly that I still can apply the chi-squared test for each pair and adjust the p-values obtained? Or should I use a different statistical test altogether?